# Apache Server Throwing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, http

I *had* a LAMP application running wordpress and I deleted the whole directory and replaced with new files - php based.

Now, when I go to view my server running CentOS - it just shows a 500 Internal Server error.

I've tried:

1. restarting server
2. restarting apache service itself

both completed successfully, but this didn't fix anything. Now, I do not know where to go from here.

**`apache logs @ /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log`** on apache:

```
[Tue Apr 22 11:12:15 2014] [error] [] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "index.php" is smaller than min_uid
```

Comment: How about folder/file permissions? Are they set correctly? Another thing to look for if this is a production server is a PHP error when you have errors set to not show in php.ini.

Comment: What should a public_html be set to?

Comment: Can you check the server logs to see if shows any more detail?

Comment: That depends on your application. Why not remove it and try running a simple info.php or something like that? Most of the time directories will be 755. You can set that with something like sudo /path/to/app find -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

Comment: Did you check that your errors arent PHP related? Try setting "display_errors" to 1 in your php.ini for the moment.

Comment: I set the public_html dir with chmod to 755, that didnt fix it. I checked my apache logs. I'm posting an error now

Comment: How are you connecting to MySQL? With /tmp/mysql.sock?

Comment: Added the error_log from apache

Comment: I'm not connecting to Mysql for this application

Comment: Perhaps, "UID of script "index.php" is smaller than min_uid" this is causing it ?

Comment: There's your error then.

Comment: Remove your IP address from what you posted.

Comment: Fixed it. I posted the answer, hopefully it'll help a fellow stackoverflower. Appreciate the help in trying to debug everyone!

Comment: I think this is a cPanel problem; apache has no file "Application.cpp"

Comment: @DanFromGermany - potentially, but I wondered how it turned into a permissions issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the fix myself, this wasn't an error with Mysql at all, but rather a permissions issue with the index.php file I had.

The error, which I found in `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` was:
    :is smaller than min_uid Premature end of script headers: index.php

**To fix, I did this:**

1. `ls -l` in the directory causing the issue (mine was `public_html`)
2. You should see the index file (e.g. index.php) that should be causing the issue. It is due to a `root` user having the only permission to the file and not your CPanel (or system) username. (note this system/cpanel name)
3. Run the following within the errorneous directory(**Note**: this command must be run within all subdirectories of the primary errorneous directory.):

   ```
   sudo chown yoursystemuserhere:yoursystemgroupuserhere index.php
   ```

   or to apply to the whole directory (thanks to @Prix):

   ```
   sudo chown -R user:group /folder
   ```
4. You're all set.

Further literature here: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/general-server-setup/uid-smaller-than-min-uid

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: or you could use `chown -R user:group /folder` and it will recursively apply the change to all files and sub folders.

Comment: As I did after posting this. Good call out here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar symptoms on my cPanel VPS - I was able to [use easyApache to recompile Apache and PHP](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-upgrade-apache-and-php-using-cpanels-easyapache/) which fixed the problem for me.

(I realise my problem was slightly different to yours, but it may be helpful for people in the future who have the same problem I had).

Answer (score 1):

```
chown -R user.usergroup /path_to_the_directory
```

Will resolve this. It is basically permission issues.

Answer (score -2):

just install wordpress latest version make sure you have atleast php version 5.3 and above also look global register variable if it off or just delete htacess file from server and see what will happens
generally 500 internal server gives when file permission is missing so you should delete htacess file

Comment: Im not looking to make a new wordpress site... did you see the question?